# Translation for "Tail value at risk"

Tags: traducción

I'm stuck with this translation.

I know that **Value at risk** (*VaR*) is ***Valor en riesgo***. But how do you translate **Tail Value at Risk**?

---

Some definitions taken from *Loss Models* (Klugman S., *et al.*):

> Let *X* denote a random variable. The **Value-at-risk** of *X* at the *100p%* level is the *p%* percentile (or quantile) of the distribution of *X*
>
> The **Tail-Value-at-Risk** of *X* is the expected loss given that the loss exceeds the *100p%* percentile (or quantile) of the distribution of *X*

The only thing I can think of is *valor medio de riesgo en exceso*. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El [Diccionario MAPFRE de Seguros](http://www.mapfre.com/wdiccionario/terminos/vertermino.shtml?v/valor-en-riesgo-en-la-cola.htm) sugiere

> valor en riesgo en la cola (tail value at risk)

Y da la siguiente definición:

> Definición: Medida de riesgo definida como el nivel de pérdida
>   esperado condicionado a que se supere el umbral de pérdidas del v.a.r.
>   Formalmente, el t.v.a.r. se puede definir como la pérdida esperada en
>   una cartera en el q% de los peores casos en un horizonte t.
>
> Sinónimo de valor en riesgo condicional o expected shortfall.

Answer (score 2):

También se le puede encontrar nombrado como (todo es lo mismo):

- (riesgo de) deficiencia esperada (o media) (del inglés expected shortfall)
- Valor en riesgo condicional (CVaR en inglés, lo he visto en español como CVeR tratando de asemejarse a las siglas en inglés)
- Valor en riesgo esperado (o medio) (AVaR en inglés)
- Pérdida esperada (o media) en la cola

Teniendo en cuenta que el valor de la media también es llamado esperanza en estadística, por tanto valor esperado (o medio). 
También teniendo en cuenta que cuando habla de valor en riesgo condicional, se refiere a la condición de que se supere el 'valor en riesgo' (que es la previsión de riesgo en condiciones normales), por lo que valor en riesgo condicional es un valor más allá del valor en riesgo, superando esa condición, un valor en condiones de volatilidad o incertidumbre.